# Help solving Boundary Condition Ordinary Differential Equation with absolute value.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value, boundary-value-problem

Good day everybody.
I'm a physics student enrolled in a scientific computation course and my teacher sent us a bunch of ODEs to solve both analitically and numerically. I haven't really studied boundary value problems so maybe I need to be pointed to a resource for that but right now I'm but having trouble with this one in particular:
$$u'' + 9u = 36(5- |x|)^2$$
with the boundary conditions $u(-5) = 0$ and $u(5) = 0$.

My attempt at solving it goes like this:

1. I expand and separate the equation in its two domains
   $$u"+ 9u = 36x^2 + 360x + 900, \ x < 0$$
   $$u"+ 9u = 36x^2 -  360x + 900, \ x \ge 0$$
   Now I have two equations so I believe I need two homogeneous solutions, two particular solutions and four conditions. Therefore
2. I solve for to the homogeneous part:
   $$U_h(x) = A\cos(3x) + B\sin(3x), \ x<0$$
   $$U_h(x) = C\cos(3x) + D\sin(3x), \ x\ge 0$$
3. I resort to undetermined coefficients looking for particular solutions:
   $$U_p(x) = 4x^2+40x + 892/9, \ x < 0$$
   $$U_p(x) = 4x^2-40x + 892/9, \ x \ge 0$$
4. I add $U_h$ and $U_p$ to make two general solutions:
   $$U(x) = A\cos(3x) + B\sin(3x) + 4x^2+40x + \frac{892}{9}, \ x<0 $$
   $$U(x) = C\cos(3x) + D\sin(3x) + 4x^2-40x + \frac{892}{9}, \ x\ge0 $$
5. This is where I notice I have only two boundary conditions, not four.

So, there is that. Should I merge both solutions back togheter into one? or maybe two conditions are enough and that's what I'm not seeing. Anyway, I hope you guys can help.

Comment: You should have continuity $u(0^+) = u(0^-)$ and $u'(0^+) = u'(0^-)$, which should imply that $A = C$ and $3B + 40 = 3D - 40$. The remaining two conditions are at the boundary.

Comment: Thanks, now I can solve it. Are those conditions always necessary or are implied in this problem somehow?

Comment: Always necessary is a bit strong. You're solving a differential equation. Somewhere in the early part of the textbook, they probably state that $u,u'$ are continuous and differentiable. We are merely enforcing that condition at the point where these solutions meet in this case.